# SpringMVC check server is UP or DOWN

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, webserver, server

How can I check if my server is UP or DOWN in SpringMVC or just simple in JAVA?
I want a simple function how receiving a URL as a parameter and return just one boolean variable TRUE or FALSE which represents a SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
public class HealthCheckController {
    @RequestMapping("/healthcheck")
    public Greeting greeting() {
        return "up";
    }
}
```

When you have to check if the server is up just send get request to `/healthcheck`. If it returns "up", you're OK.

If you use Spring Boot, you can take a look at `actuator`. It allows this functionality out of the box plus some other stuff like datasource checking and so on